# Execute a javascript inside PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm using a pre-made template in HTML with Bootstrap and jQuery. It's one of those sites where only `index.php` is available, and you navigate to the different sections of the `index.php` by some interactive navigation buttons.

In the verification I'm doing a query if in the database ther is a "verification required" field filled with a 'Y', if yes, I'm setting the `$msg` to

```
<?php if(isset($msg)) { echo $msg } ?>
```

I tried to do

```
<?php if(isset($msg)) { echo '<script type=text/javascript>'.$msg.'</script>' } ?>
```

and set `$msg` to the script name, it sadly isn't working though, and I really don't know how to correct it!

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: which code exactly?

Comment: I don't know how it works or what keywords to use for people to understand it, I'm using a pre-made template, that's why I don't know how to describe the exact function of that "interactive website"!

Comment: You can totally have PHP echo out working Javascript...it's just a bad practice and tends to be a nightmare to maintain. Try to `alert` your message, I guess...`if(isset($msg)) { echo '<script type=text/javascript>alert('.$msg.');</script>' }`

Comment: you just want to show popup right? using single page like @HPierce said right?

Comment: try read this https://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: I'm just getting an alertbox with the content .$msg. then @cteski :(

Comment: yes @ntaloventi

Comment: @ntaloventi to the dialog, I wanted to use this https://limonte.github.io/sweetalert2/ I've set up everything etc, I just don't know how to call that script with the php if-clause changing my $msg :(

Comment: `<?php if(isset($msg)) { echo $msg } ?>` only run on first time page load, but you need after user action/intearction you need javascript for listen your action

Comment: So, I have to make the if-clause in javascript instead of PHP? Can I do mysql queries in javascript?

Answer (score 0):

What you typically do in this scenario to pass PHP simple state changes to JS is to set an element in your HTML from your PHP that your Javascript can come along and check for. The data attribute on HTML elements is a good candidate for this as its extensible.

For example:

```
<div id="message" data-popup="<?php if($msg ? 'true' : 'false'); ?>">MyMessage Here</div>

var myMessageElement = document.getElementById('message');
$(document).ready = function(){
  if( $('#message').data('popup') ){
      alert('do something');
  }
}
```

The alternative to that, is to serve a PHP file directly as Javascript to pass out your variables, but this approach will need you to set headers, and can become messy pretty quickly.